# How do I upgrade postgresl database? Incompatibility error

Tags: linux, postgresql, upgrade

I installed postgresql via Homebrew.

I have the following issue after upgrading:

`FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.0, which is not compatible with this version 9.1.2.`

Any tips on how to upgrade? I tried the following:

```
$ pg_upgrade -d /usr/local/var/postgres/ -D /usr/local/var/postgres -b 
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/bin -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/bin
```

It didn't work. Here's the output.

```
Performing Consistency Checks
Checking current, bin, and data directories                 ok
Checking cluster versions                                   
This utility can only upgrade to PostgreSQL version 9.1.
Failure, exiting
```

error.